# Can we make the cartesian product of a field with itself into a field in a meaningful way?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be a field, then the set $K^n$ is an $n$ dimensional vector space over $K$ in a canonical way. My question is, can we turn $K^n$ into a field in a way that the multiplication operation is "useful" in some sense? Because, for example, we can define entrywise multiplication of vectors in $K^n$ as a binary operation over $K^n$ that gives it a commutative ring structure. I cannot make it into a field, and I cannot come up with any operation that feels right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the $K$-vector space $K^n$ can be made into a field if and only if there is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over $K$, by the primitive element theorem (assuming that $K$ is perfect). So, if $K$ is algebraically closed (which implies that $K$ is also perfect) and $n>1$, then $K^n$ cannot be made into a field.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we can't. In some particular cases, we can. For instance, $\Bbb C$ is just $\Bbb R^2$ with a multiplication defined by$$(a,b).(c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc).$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: \mathbb{K}^n\to \mathbb{K} $ be any bijection. Then define $$a\oplus b =f^{-1} (f(a) +f(b))$$
$$a\cdot b =f^{-1} (f(a) f(b))$$
Then $(\mathbb{K}^n ,\oplus , \cdot )$ is a field.

Comment: I don't think it's clear why this map will $0\in K^n$ to $0\in K$. And the addition you have is not the same as the canonical addition operation we have on $K^n$.

Comment: It is easy to see that must be $(\mathbb{K}^n ,\oplus ,\cdot)\ni 0 = f^{-1} (0) .$ But this have not to be the usual zero.

Comment: So you're completely disregarding the algebraic structure on $K^n$? I don't know if that is what the OP wants but it would be a silly thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a field structure depending on what $K$ is.

For example, if $K=\mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{Q}$), we have $\mathbb{C}\supset \mathbb{R}$.

So if we define $(a,b)\times (c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\mathbb{R}^2$ is endowed with a "multiplication" that makes it isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ so it would be a field.

Can this be done for any field and any $n$? No, of course not. Maybe you could try to do it for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and see that it will fail. But the discussion above will give you an idea of what algebraic properties we need for $K$.